# Unix random 16 character number

Tags: unix, random, numbers

Hey need help in unix creating a random 16 character long number using 0-9 but the first number being not 0 (1-9).

tr -c -d 0-9 < /dev/urandom | fold -w16

something like this but first number not being 0

Answer (score 0):

First, generate a 1-digit random number using the digits `1-9`.

Second, generate a 15-digit random number using the digits `0-9`.

Then, combine these two numbers.

Comment: is this possible with 1 line?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Every shell script that doesn't use here-documents can be written in a single line.

Comment: how would you do this than? Would they not 1+1= 2 instead of 1+1=11?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on ***UNIX***, you can use `jot` with arguments from bash integer expansion:

```
jot -r 1 $((10 ** 15)) $((((10 ** 15)) * 2))
```

Generates numbers like:

```
1595866171875968
```